# Notepad++ search and replace xml ids

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is there any way to search and replace a name="" attribute with unique names in notepad++? I simply want to remove the whole name="" attribute.

Is there any way in notepad++ to do this with a regex?

The name attribute looks like this:

```
name="myTag1"
```

Where `1` is a unique id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the replace function with this regex

```
name="myTag[0-9]+"
```

Don't forget to check the `regular expression` checkbox in the replace function dialog.